# What is the syntax for invoking a function with named parameters in Visual Cobol?

Tags: cobol, microfocus, cobol.net

How do I use named parameters when INVOKEing a function? In this case I am calling a c# static method, i.e.

```
INVOKE TYPE ClassName::FunctionName(PARAMETER-VALUE-1, PARAMETER-VALUE-2)
```

Comment: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60win%2FHRLHLHPDF790.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

invoke type ClassName::Method(param *parmName* = *parmValue*, parameter *parmName* = *parmValue*)

Note param or parameter can be used as the keyword. A space can be used instead of a comma separator as well

e.g:

invoke type classname::Method(param StringParm = "a String", parameter IntParm = 100)